# Azure Data Bricks Sql - Producing extended date time string

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 3 columns as follows :

- Created datetime – 03/04/2021 4.25pm ( DATE data type )
- Created dtm ( seconds ) – 50  ( INT )
- Created dtm ( milliseconds) – 979 ( INT )

I need a single column like : 03/04/2021 4:25:50:979

In Azure Data Bricks sql , is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some string methods to get the desired datetime string:

```
select 
    replace(
        concat_ws(':', 
            regexp_replace(datetime, '[a-z]', ''), dtm_seconds, dtm_milliseconds
        ), 
        '.', ':'
    ) as newcol
from mytable;
```